# Create function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I try to create function in Oracle SQL Plus, but why Do I get compilation Error is it because the spacing not correct, I am using notepad so I have to manually enter all the spacing, any application to recommend for me to code SQL so that the spacing is automatically added like in VS Code?

I am trying to create a function return 'True' or 'False' if the Check_Out field and Reason_Cancel field is null for the guest with the guest id parse in.

```
DROP FUNCTION Check_Room_Booked;

CREATE FUNCTION Check_Room_Booked(
guest_nric VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURN VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN 
  IF (SELECT COUNT(Guest) FROM BOOKING WHERE Guest = guest_nric AND Check_out IS NULL AND Reason_Cancel IS NULL) < 2 THEN RETURN 'True' ELSE RETURN 'False'
END;
/
```

Comment: Spacing has no meaning in PL/SQL. You will indeed get compilation errors with that code, but they have nothing to do with "spacing".

Comment: when you get compile errors, issue the sqlplus 'show error' command.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look up that command and see what it does.

Comment: Download Oracle SQL Developer.  It may not be the best IDE but it is Free and database aware.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues with the function you are trying to define.  The example below probably achieves what you are attempting to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check_Room_Booked (guest_nric VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (Guest)
      INTO l_count
      FROM BOOKING
     WHERE Guest = guest_nric AND Check_out IS NULL AND Reason_Cancel IS NULL;

    RETURN CASE WHEN l_count < 2 THEN 'False'
                ELSE 'True' END;
END;
/
```

Comment: @mathguy - I updated the code using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very tricky.
**First**- You want TRUE/FALSE as boolean or 'TRUE'/'FALSE' as strings returned as result from function?
**Second** - False to be returned when guest with **guest_nric** has populated Check_out AND Reason_Cancel and True to be returned when Check_out IS NULL AND Reason_Cancel is NULL or vice versa?

But let us assume that function has to return 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' as string value and 'TRUE' means that there is a guest with **guest_nric**  with Check_out IS NULL AND Reason_Cancel is NULL.

Please try this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check_Room_Booked (guest_nric VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (Guest)
      INTO l_count
      FROM BOOKING
     WHERE Guest = guest_nric AND Check_out IS NULL AND Reason_Cancel IS NULL;

    RETURN CASE WHEN l_count = 0 then 'False' else 'True' end;
END;
/
```

Thanks.